# Modify http POST with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to print out Google Calendars but they only print for "letter" sized paper.  I examined the POST req. that were going out with the developer console and found that there are a bunch of options that could be modified:

```
src:---LONGSTRING---
ctz:America/Bahia
pgsz:letter
secid:----------
wkst:1
hl:pt_BR
dates:20120101/20120205
mode:MONTH
prsd:20120101
pred:20120205
pfs:NORMAL
po:AUTO
psdec:false
pbw:true
pjs:false
rand:---------
pda:true
```

I'd like to know how to make a **chrome extension** that would allow you to select different page sizes (I tried a4 and it works).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend reading over the Chrome Extensions Developer guide and try out the hello world tutorial:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

The approach you might take is to add a ["content script"](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), which is a special script that has the ability to modify the DOM of the current page.  You could then add additional form fields to the google calendar print page, perhaps a select options list with a `name` of `pgsz` and have option values for the allowed sizes.